# Veritas and VNX LUN Expansion

Tags: storage, storage-area-network, veritas

I have an EMC VNX Storage array and a front end Linux server running Veritas. A 4TB lun has been assigned from a diskpool on the VNX and presented to the server where Veritas has split it out into volumes, I now need to expand one of those volumes.

In unisphere I expanded the LUN and performed a rescan in Veritas Enterprise Administrator expecting it to pickup the free space within the LUN and allow me to allocate it to a volume but this isn't working.

First time using VEAS so any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, I would actually recommend using more smaller LUNs on the storage for performance reasons. Right now, all your server's volumes are sharing a single SCSI command queue, and probably going through the same processor on the VNX. First rule in storage is to go wide before you go deep.

That said, your linux server will need some coaxing to see the new space. I found a thorough description of the process [here](http://www.standalone-sysadmin.com/blog/2009/05/resizing-storage-luns-in-linux-on-the-fly/).